# How early did primordial oxygen form?

Tags: big-bang, nucleosynthesis

[It has been suggested](https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.0613) liquid water could exist 10-17 million years after the Big Bang, warmed by the CMB instead of stars. Would Big Bang nucleosynthesis produce oxygen that soon? (Empirically, the only nuclides shown to form during BBN are those with $Z\le 3$, but I'm looking for a theoretical timescale of oxygen nucleosynthesis.)

Answer (score 1):

The oxygen is not primordial. The zany idea behind this paper is that it might just have been possible to form the first massive stars at a redshift of just over 100, about 10 million years after the big bang. These ultramassive stars would have exploded about 3 million years after they formed, seeding their surroundings with heavy elements, produced in *their* interiors, including oxygen, silicon, iron etc.

Any subsequent rocky planets that formed may not have needed a star to be "in the habitable zone" because the temperature of the cosmic microwave background was about 300 K at these redshifts.

I am not enough of an expert to know whether massive star formation at redshifts more than 100 is just unlikely rather than impossible - there is no observational evidence. However, a big problem that I don't see addressed is that you need to form rocky planets from a disc around a second generation of more metal-rich stars (or at least we don't have another model for this).

Those planets then have to survive the turmoil of their early solar systems and cool down (against the competing chemical differentiation and radioactive decay). In our solar system and for our Earth, that probably took another 100 million years. If that were generally true, the CMB would have cooled by another factor of a few in that time and planets away from stars would not be habitable.

I am not clear why the authors didn't just suggest that if rocky planets could form, then so could high metallicity low-mass stars with long lives...?

Answer (score -1):

No. But liquid lithium would have existed for about 75 million years.

Oxygen wasn't produced until later when the first stars formed.

Let s=size of the universe

The strength of an electric or magnetic field is proportional to the density of field lines at a given point.

The density of the field lines in the CMB = 1/s^2

The energy in an electric or magnetic field is proportional to the square of the field strength.

Therefore e=1/s^4

A blackbody absorbs all of the light energy that falls on it.

Let t=temperature of a blackbody.

The energy emitted by a blackbody is proportional to t^4.

A blackbody in space will adjust its temperature until it is emitting the same amount of energy that it is absorbing.

Therefore t^4=1/s^4

t=1/s

T=z+1

When z=1 the universe was half its present size and twice its present temperature